# Retrieve all named element from namedtuples in a subset of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

I have a list of namedtuples. I would like to generate a list of a specific named element of a subset of the namedtuples in the list, based on a list of indices to select.

Example would be:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import itemgetter

NameTuple = namedtuple("NameTuple", ['first_name', 'last_name'])
name1=NameTuple(first_name='John',last_name="Doe")
name2=NameTuple(first_name="Jane",last_name="Doe")
name3=NameTuple(first_name="Jason",last_name="Smith")
namelist=[name1,name2,name3]
```

While itemgetter and a list comprehension works when selecting 2 items:

```
inds1 = [0,1]
sublist = list(itemgetter(*inds1)(namelist))
[item.first_name for item in sublist]
```

Similar code using an index list of 1 fails:

```
inds2=[0]
sublist = list(itemgetter(*inds2)(namelist))
[item.first_name for item in sublist]
```

which throws an Attribute error. This is happening because sublist in this case has flattened the elements of NameTuple into a list, rather than returning a list of 1 NameTuple.

So how to avoid this flattening? I would like to have code that takes a generalized list or even None (meaning all elements) properly.

Comment: You cannot use list comprehension on an item that is not a list, for example `namelist[0]`. You instead want to directly call `namelist[0].first_name`

Comment: "using a subset of the list ", well, `nameList[0]` **doesn't** create a subset of your list, it simply gets the first element. What, exactly, are you trying to subset?

Comment: In general nameList would have more than 2 items so this is clearer. I will revise the question above to better illustrate this. I think the problem is arising because the tuples are themselves iterable and so when one selects only one of them, the elements are iterated over, rather than a list of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your problem iteration clause:

... for item in namelist[0]

This is *not* iterating through a subset of the namedtuples; it iterates through the field of `namelist[0]`, which is another reference to `name1`.  This iteration iterates `item` through `name1.firstname` and `name1.lastname`.  THose are strings, *not* objects with a `firstname` field.

Yes, you can iterate through a subset of your list, but that is *not* what you used.  Perhaps you would want a specific sublist, such as

```
... for item in [namelist[0]]
```

*This* is a list of one element, which *does* have the required field.

---

**Solution to emended problem**

Extract your items more directly, instead of going through `itemgetter`-- use the given subscripts:

```
# While itemgetter and a list comprehension works when selecting 2 items:

inds1 = [0,1]
print( [namelist[idx].first_name for idx in inds1] )

# Similar code using an index list of 1 fails:

inds2=[0]
print( [namelist[idx].first_name for idx in inds2] )
```

Output:

```
['John', 'Jane']
['John']
```

This works even with an empty list of indices.

Comment: That seems to be the essence of the issue. How to iterate through a general subset of the list specified by indices given as a list without iterating through the fields of a namedtuple when the indices only select one named tuple.